# Send response in html templates without reload page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, django

In  my Django project i have a listing page for all customers.
On that page all customers list shows, i have a filed is_active there.
I if i click on change status button ( every row of customer listing page have a change status button) is_active field become false without reloading my listing page.and when i again clcik on change status button it turn True.Please help me by giving a sample code for it.
MY listing page is as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform"  method = "POST" action="#">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>time</th>
    <th>fb_id</th>
    <th>contact_number</th>
    <th>is_active</th>
    <th>Action</th>

  </tr>
  {% for lead in leads %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{lead.customer_name}}</td>
    <td>{{lead.location}}</td>  
    <td>{{lead.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{lead.time_requirement}}</td>
    <td>{{lead.fb_id}}</td>
    <td>{{lead.contact_number}}</td>
    <td>
        {%  if lead.is_active %}
        <input type="radio" value="" checked>
        {% else %}
        <input type="radio" value="" >
        {% endif %}
        <button name="button" value="OK" type="button" >change status</button>

        </td>
    <td><button name="button" value="OK" type="button" align="middle"><a href="/customapi/vendor/detail-customer-leads/?lead_id={{lead.id}}">Edit</a></button>
    </td>



  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this usnig **AJAX**

Fisrt of all you have to define an AJAX view:

```
from .model import Customer# import here your model
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def ajax_view(request):
    results = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('pk',None)
        if pk:
            customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=pk)
            results['code'] = 200
            if customer.is_active:
                customer.is_active = False 
                results['status'] = 'inactive'
            else:
                customer.is_active = True
                results['status'] = 'active'
            customer.save()
        else:
            results['code'] = 404
    else:
        results['code'] = 500
    return JsonResponse(results)
```

Then create a new url in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^activeConsumer$', views.ajax_view, name ="active_consumer"),
```

After that in your Template you define an **AJAX** call using `JQuery`:

```
<script>
 function active_consumer(id) {
   //AJAX DATA
    //you have to send data to server
    // first you have to get the id of the consumer
    // second you have to pass `csrfmiddlewaretoken` with data 
   data = {
     'pk':id,
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{csrf_token}}' };

    //AJAX CALL
    $.post( "{% url 'active_consumer' %}", data).done(function(response) {
        if (response.code == 200) {
            if (response.status == "active") {
                 //here you have to change the status of the consumer to active in HTML
             }
             else {
                 //here you have to change the status of the consumer to inactive in HTML
             }
            }
        });
      }
</script>
```

In your HTML you make a call to the javascript function `active_consumer` :

```
<button name="button" value="OK" type="button" onclick="active_consumer({{lead.id}})" >change status</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

to check or uncheck the radio button , you must give it an `id`:

```
{%  if lead.is_active %}
<input id="myradio" type="radio" value="" checked>
{% else %}
<input id="myradio" type="radio" value="" >
{% endif %}
```

To check the radio button using `JQuery`:

```
$("#myradio").prop("checked", true)
```

To uncheck it:

```
$("#myradio").prop("checked", false)
```

So the javascript function will be  like this:

```
<script>
 function active_consumer(id) {
   data = {
     'pk':id,
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{csrf_token}}' };


    $.post( "{% url 'active_consumer' %}", data).done(function(response) {
        if (response.code == 200) {
            if (response.status == "active") {
                 //uncheck the radio button
                 $("#myradio").prop("checked", false)  
             }
             else {
                 //check the radio button
                 $("#myradio").prop("checked", true)
             }
            }
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Helllo Messaoud  .Is javascipt fucntion complete or i have to write something extra.Please help me in this i dont know ajax so i am unable to execute when i write exact code which you sent me.

Comment: Hi @vikrantVerma, yes is almost complete you have just to `check`  or `uncheck` the radio button , i'll update my answer

Comment: AttributeError at /customapi/vendor/active-customer/
'bool' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: this error is showing when i click change status button

Comment: you have wriiten consumar and customer in view.is it typo error

Comment: `customer` is just an example, you have to modify it with your real `model`

Comment: `if customer_lead.is_active:
    print "3"
    customer_lead = False
    results['status'] = 'inactive'
   else:
    print "3 else"
    customer_lead.is_active = True
    results['status'] = active
   customer_lead.save()`

Comment: this is my real when i execute this it saying me error 'bool' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: you have an error in you code here `customer_lead = False` , must be `customer_lead.is_active = False`